# ArrayList<A> conversion to ArrayList<B> when A implements B Java

Tags: java, interface, arraylist

I'm quite new to Java, and I have a question about method invocation conversion.

I've made a new class that extends ArrayList called ListableList - but that does not seem to be the problem.

The problem is I have a method that looks like this

```
public static void printList(ListableList<Listable> list, String seperator){
    for(Listable item : list){
        System.out.println(seperator);
        System.out.println(item.toList());
    }
    System.out.println(seperator);
}
```

I call this method like this:

```
Output.printList(rules, "..");
```

Where rules is initialized as

```
rules = new ListableList<Rule>();
```

And Rule implements Listable.

When I try to compile I get:

```
required: ListableList<Listable>,String
found: ListableList<Rule>,String
reason: actual argument ListableList<Rule> cannot be converted to ListableList<Listable> by method invocation conversion
```

Why is this, from what I've learned, this should work??
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to change your method signature of printList to:

```
public static void printList(ListableList<? extends Listable> list, String seperator){
```

Generic Types are **not polymorphic,** I.e., `Listable<Listable>` is not a super type of `List<Rule>` even though **Rule** is a `sub-type` of **Listable**. You will have to use [**generics with upper bounded wildcards**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) in your method signature to inform that your List can accept anything which is a sub-type of Listable. Note that you cannot add anything into your list if you use `Generics with upperbounded wildcards`. I.e,

```
public static void printList(ListableList<? extends Listable> list, String seperator){
      list.add(whatever); // is not allowed
```

### Useful Links

- [**An Awesome Tutorial for generics in java**](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html)

Answer (score 2):

Please use:

```
public static void printList(ListableList<? extends Listable> list, String seperator){
```

This means that list is a readonly collections, which contains subclasses of Listable.

`ListableList<Rule>` is not assign-compatible to `ListableList<Listable>` because you can add non Rule objects to a `ListableList<Listable>`.

Answer (score 1):

Method declaration should be like `printList(ListableList<? extends Listable> list, String seperator)`. Make it generic.